# Do you need to clear immigration when connecting at DXB Terminal 1?

Tags: transit, dubai, connecting-flights, dxb

As I have never been to Dubai Airport T1, I wanted to ask whether arriving passengers can remain airside and board their onward flight without having to pass immigration.
I am well aware that this is possible at T3, since Emirates uses the airport as a hub. But passengers on airlines arriving at T1 will most likely not connect to another flight (or at least not on one ticket and thus most likely need to clear immigration to recheck luggage).

My intention would be to fly the triangle CDG-DXB-AMS for the simple reason of flying on a B787-10. STA from Paris 22:35, STD to AMS at 00:40. With my passport I don't need a visa for the UAE and I would travel with hand luggage only.

Comment: Arrival and departure in T1? I think it is possible, and you may get (with the airside train) also to T3 (and back). I think you are wrong about not many people with connecting tickets: most of alliances have Asian and European partners, DXB could be a good connecting airport (but not an hub).

Comment: AFAIK you can just follow the red signs for connections and remain airside to reach any terminal/concourse (though going to/from T2 requires taking an airside bus). And of course Marhaba will transfer checked baggage for you on separate tickets (for a fee) so you don't even have to clear immigration in that case.